# Sobre la expresión "dar papaya" en otros países

Tags: diferencias-regionales, modismos, significado, expresiones, colombia

*Dar papaya* [significa](http://aerocolombia.com/2011/09/24/dar-papaya-o-no-dar-papaya/):

> Dar innecesariamente la oportunidad para que suceda algo, exponerse, arriesgarse, ponerse en peligro, ser descuidado, ser imprudente, ser inocente, dar todas las facilidades para que suceda algo, dar demasiada ventaja a alguien...

Al parecer, es una expresión netamente colombiana y muy popular, así que tengo curiosidad de saber lo siguiente:

1. Si en otros países es utilizada con el mismo significado.
2. Si en otros países es utilizada, pero tiene un significado diferente.
3. Si hay expresiones propias de cada país que signifiquen lo mismo que *dar papaya*.

Comment: En México no se utiliza esa expresión. Me resulta curiosa y no encuentro relación entre la misma y su uso coloquial. Una expresión utilizada en México para el mismo uso, sería: ¨ponerse de pechito¨, haciendo alusión a los pájaros cuando están en una posición totalmente frontal y favorable para dispararles (estando de cazería).

Comment: En España tampoco se utiliza. Por cierto, hay un pseudo diccionario muy interesante: el Bogotalogo, con explicación de palabras y definiciones típicas de Bogotá, Colombia. Ved cómo explica ["dar papaya"](http://bogotalogo.com/wiki/index.php?title=Papaya_%28dar%29)

Comment: En Chile no se usa "dar papaya", pero sí existe "papaya" o "papa" con el significado de "fácil". La prueba estuvo papaya, la pregunta era papa.

Comment: En Guatemala no se usa porque la papaya es una fruta.
Aquí sería: ¡te robaron por que diste facilidad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que no había escuchado nunca la expresión, pero comprobando [el DRAE](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=papaya)

> Papaya
>
> dar ~ a alguien.
>   1. loc. verb. coloq. **Col**. Darle oportunidad.

Por lo que parece que el DRAE indica que es una expresión coloquial propia de Colombia..

No sé si hay un recurso con una lista de expresiones que signifiquen lo mismo que "dar oportunidad". Probablemente variará con el país. A mi ahora mismo me viene a la cabeza para España

- Poner a huevo
- Poner en bandeja

Comment: La primera me suena española (¿qué tanto se utilizará en otros países?) y la segunda la había escuchado como *poner en bandeja de plata*.

Comment: @David, creo que ese es el origen. Si no me equivoco hay un pasaje bíblico en el que Herodes entrega a Salomé la cabeza de Juan Bautista **en bandeja de plata**. Literalmente. Salomé quería vengarse de Juan Bautista y los soldados de Herodes le cortaron la cabeza, la pusieron en una bandeja de plata y se la mostraron a Salomé. Creo que las dos expresiones significan lo mismo (una es simplemente una versión abreviada).

Answer (score 4):

Dar papaya significa "descuidarse", "dar oportunidad", "distraerse", en el argot coloquial de los colombianos. Asimismo, es una descripción de algo demasiado fácil, comparable con tomar un pedazo de dicha fruta cuando está madura, la cual se encuentra silvestre en la flora del país cafetero.

Comment: Muchas gracias por aportar el origen de la expresión, que no teníamos en ninguna de las respuestas anteriores. Y bienvenido.

Answer (score 3):

En Venezuela también usamos la expresión "dar papaya" y significa "dar oportunidad"

> *Te robaron el carro porque diste mucha papaya*.

O sea, la persona se expuso y dio facilidad al ladrón para robar el carro, probablemente lo dejó abierto en un lugar peligroso.

Answer (score 1):

En Cuba, papaya se puede usar para referir a una vagina.  Entonces "dar papaya" toma otro sentido completamente.