# ¿Es "chilote" una palabrota?

Tags: coloquialismos, chile

> - A: ¡Hola, weón!
>   - B: ¿Cómo tay, chilote?
>   - A: Toy bien y ¿vos?
>   - B: ¡Un siete, **chilote**!

¿Es un insulto llamar a alguien "chilote"?

Comment: Dúdolo. Tanto por su entrada en el DRAE (gentilicio para Chiloé, Chile) y por el contexto que das (amistoso e informal), es evidente que insulto no es (aunque en otros contextos no sé por no usar la palabra)

Comment: Se puede imaginar que toy=estoy, tay=estás En cualquier caso, y a pesar de tratarse de una conversación informal, el diálogo mejoraría mucho sin las faltas de ortografía y puntuación: _Toy bien y ¿vos?_  --> Estoy bien, ¿Y vos?

Comment: @Ra_ En el lenguaje coloquial chileno es común pronunciar así esas formas verbales, de ahí que estén escritas adrede de esa forma.

Answer (score 3):

**No** es un insulto. Es el gentilicio de la zona de Chiloé, un hermoso archipiélago al sur de Chile.

El diálogo que transcribes claramente se desarrolla entre chilenos. Tanto *weón* como *chilote* son sólo epítetos informales, no insultos. *Weón* es una forma estandarizada que tenemos los chilenos para tratarnos con familiaridad (aunque a veces sí es un insulto). Y *chilote* se refiere al lugar de origen del hablante A.

Comment: No es un insulto *a priori*, pero según el contexto puede llegar a usarse de forma peyorativa. En Argentina se usa a veces informalmente *chilote* para referirse a los chilenos en general, no siempre de manera amable.

Comment: y que quiere decir "un siete?"

Comment: @aris La escala de calificaciones de los exámenes en Chile va de 1 a 7. Un siete es la mejor calificación, entonces significa _excelente_. Equivale a lo que en otros países es _un diez_ o una A.

Answer (score 1):

Por otro lado, en Mexico **chilote** es usualmente un altisonante, que -usualmente- se refiere a las *asombrosas* dimensiones de los genitales de algún involucrado en la conversación; usualmente quien usa dicha palabra para expresar insultantemente algún acto sexual con el interpelado o su parentela.

Por otro lado, el contexto de la pregunta es claramente una conversación que se llevó a cabo en alguna austral región hispanoparlante, por lo que en esa instancia *podría no ser palabrota.*

El castellano se usa de muchas maneras atraves de toda Hispanoamérica y la Península Ibérica. Solo porque en una región una palabra sea perfectamente inofensiva, no quere decir que usarla no los ponga en aprietos en otra región tambien hispanoparlante.

Hagan la prueba de pedir "**Papaya**" en un puesto de fruta **cubano**. Recomiendo que mejor compren "*Frutabomba*" si no quieren tener cargos por acoso sexual en la isla.

Comment: ¡Curioso lo de dar papaya! Sería bueno incluirlo en [Sobre la expresión “dar papaya” en otros países](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14867/1674)